# Pass variables to Jade without Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Quick question about the Jade template engine:

- How can you pass `node.js` variables to a `.jade` template when you're not using `express.js`?

I'm trying to make a small website that doesn't use express, just so that I can understand how everything works.

Also, are there tutorials or articles about the use of Jade and `node.js` without express?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var jade = require('jade');
jade.renderFile('tpl.jade', { hello: 'world' }, function(err, html) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(html);
});
```

**tpl.jade:**

```
html
  body
    h1 #{hello}
```

Comment: So, from what I understand, the variable hello will be replaced by the string 'world'. How does this example look on the jade side of things ? Thanks for your quick answer !

Comment: Thank you kind sir for this answer! I couldn't find this in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

[Vadim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12322449/1476885)'s answer is nice, but old. It uses a different syntax to declare Jade variables then what is used currently at Jade's [official tutorial](http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/#Javascript). Also, it does not show how to use [Jade options](http://jade-lang.com/api/).

### Simple Example

**index.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= pageTitle
  body
    h1= greetings
```

In this example, variables are **pageTitle** and **greetings**.

**app.js**

```js
var jade = require('jade');

var locals = {
  pageTitle : 'My Page',
  greetings : 'Hello World!'
};

jade.renderFile('index.jade', locals, function(err, html) {
  console.log(html);
});
```

**Output:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>My Page</title></head><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>
```

### Using Jade Options

The previous example outputs the HTML without pretty print. That's not a problem, but Jade has an option that outputs pretty printed HTML. You can see the full list of options [here](http://jade-lang.com/api/).

Jade's [official tutorial](http://jade-lang.com/tutorial) doesn't teach how to use options when you also have variables in your template. Jade's [GitHub page](https://github.com/jadejs/jade) tries to teach, but is incomplete. It uses:

```js
jade.renderFile('filename.jade', merge(options, locals));
```

As `merge` is an undefined function, you have to define it. This function will merge two JSON objects.

**app.js**

```js
var jade = require('jade');

function merge(obj1, obj2) {
  var result = {};

  for(var key in obj1) 
    result[key] = obj1[key];

  for(var key in obj2) 
    result[key] = obj2[key];

  return result;
}

var options = {
  pretty : true
};

var locals = {
  pageTitle : 'My Page',
  greetings : 'Hello World!'
};

jade.renderFile('index.jade', merge(options, locals), function(err, html) {    
  console.log(html);
});
```

**Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: fyi, instead of creating that merge function, use Object.assign instead